# Building expression tree dynamically with typecasting

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-6, expression-trees

(Edited):

I have my class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ContractEmployee : Employee
{
    public int ContractMonth {get;set;}
}

public class Remuneration
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
    public int Amount {get;set;}
}
```

I can query Contract month like this (Using Employee as base type):

> 1st case:
>
> ```
> r => (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).Amount > 10000
> ```
>
> Corrected:
>
> ```
> r => (r.Employee is ContractEmployee) && r.Amount > 10000
> ```
>
> 2nd case:
>
> ```
> _context.Remunerations.Where(r => (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).ContractMonth > 10);
> ```

I need to create this expression

```
r => (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).ContractMonth > 10
```

dynamically.

Suppose, I get this string "Employee.ContractMonth > 10" and it will be known that I need to convert it onto ContractEmployee while coding.

I can convert this into an expression as follows:

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(Remuneration).GetProperty("Employee.ContractMonth");
ParameterExpression lhsParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Remuneration));
Expression lhs = Expression.Property(lhsParam, p);
Expression rhs = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType("10", pi.PropertyType));
Expression myoperation = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThan, lhs, rhs);
```

The above code will not work because "ContractMonth" does not belong to the class "Employee".

> How can I typecast Employee as ContractEmployee using Expression Tree:
> r => (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).ContractMonth > 10

Thanks

Comment: `(r.Employee as ContractEmployee)` still does not have an `Amount` property, only `Id`, `Name`, and `ContractMonth`.

Comment: Can you just use `_context.Remunerations.OfType<ContractEmployee>.Where(r => r.Employee.Amount > 10000);` and then dynamically build expresison without cast?

Comment: oh after reading it, you just doing query wrong

Comment: @vittore  And How do I achieve it when I have to create an expression: r =>
 (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).ContractMonth > 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access property on the wrong object.

You have

```
r => (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).Amount > 10000
```

While it should be:

```
r => (r.Employee is ContractEmployee) && r.Amount > 10000
```

I'm leaving it to you to build expression from this lambda

Something like this:

```
Expression.And(
            Expression.TypeIs(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "r"), typeof(ContractEmployee)),
            Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "r"), "Ammount"), Expression.Constant(10000))
        )
```

Comment: Thanks @vittore. And How do I achieve it when I have to create an expression: r => (r.Employee as ContractEmployee).ContractMonth > 10

Comment: I got the solution for 2 problems here. Expression.TypeAs(....) solves the other problem. Got the clue from the above answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user1731788 yes, `Expression.TypeAs` it is. Glad it helped!